# how to give positions to textview in linearlayout in android programmatically

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-linearlayout

I created a text view using this code, I want place this text view at the top of the lineaelayout(means like header)

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(Schedule.this);
                valueTV.setText("Event in Progress");
                valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                valueTV.setTypeface(TypeFaceConstant.getOpensasItalic(getApplicationContext()));
                valueTV.setId(0);
                valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                valueTV.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                lnr_list_event.addView(valueTV);
```

My xml file is ...
I want to place above text view at first positiov(top), with using above code it placed at last... pls help me

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lnr_list_event"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnr_list_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calender"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/addevent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="dfdf"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="@color/event_titles"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/event_titles"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_locationss"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/event_titles"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used above xml in list view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be better if you declare the `TextView` in the `xml` it self and `hide and show` it from the code. So there's no need of initializing the same object in each drawing.

Hiding and showing can be done with the below code

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //TO Show
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //TO Hide
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //To Hide and Release the space to otherview.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity get the root linearlayout by id, i.e. lnr_list_event. Then use method addView on the root view with index.

LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnr_list_event);

root.addView(yourHeaderView, 0, layoutparams);

Comment: Could you please tell me how we define  is layoutparams in root.addView(yourHeaderView, 0, layoutparams);

Comment: It works i used    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);     Thank you Thomas:)

Comment: Your welcome. You don't even need to specify the weight. But that's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.header);

TextView valueTV = new TextView(Schedule.this);
            valueTV.setText("Event in Progress");
            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            valueTV.setTypeface(TypeFaceConstant.getOpensasItalic(getApplicationContext()));
            valueTV.setId(0);
            valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            valueTV.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            header.addView(valueTV);
```

And xml file,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lnr_list_event"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnr_list_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/calender"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/addevent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="dfdf"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/event_titles"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/event_titles"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_locationss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/event_titles"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />
```